# change class based on page location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation on a site and I have two columns of content on the main page (one for main content, and another for sidebar). one is seven columns and the other is five columns wide but the main column is a lot longer and has more content. I was wondering if it is possible to hide one of the elements and enlarge the other based on page location or scroll.

Take something like:

```
<div id="main" class="seven columns></div>
<div id="sidebar" class="five columns></div>
```

and when the user scrolls down past where the side bar ends but main continues:

```
<div id="main" class="twelve columns></div>
<div id="sidebar" class="hide-for-all"></div>
```

So the sidebar would become hidden and main would re-size to fill in the space left, but when the user scrolls back up, it would re-appear and go back to how it was. 
I would think this is possible through jquery however I'm not sure how to do it. It would have to change a div's class based on page position, I assume.

Comment: Be careful with that logic. If you hide the sidebar and enlarge the main area, the text will reflow and cover more width and less height

Comment: This is for the first page of a blog, so the text is only an excerpt under the featured photo. it's mainly a photo blog so I want the main emphasis to be on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the distance from the top of the page in the following manner:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(); //px distance from top of page 
   //logic goes here
});
```